# How do object / class ids work?

Tags: java

I use the term object / class because I don't understand what it is actually.  From [course notes:](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~cconway/teaching/cs1007/notes/io.pdf), p33.

> **Object Versions**
>
> The serialization process assigns a version ID to every class. If we
>   change anything about the class, the version ID will change.

The heading does not match the content.

From the code, because the id is created as a static I would assume that it is per class.

But this contradicts the Heading `Object Versions`.  Plus I don't understand how we can change a "class" at run-time.

I think the professor is using the terms object and class interchangeably making things harder to understand.

Is an ID assigned per object or per class?

Comment: It is unique per *class*. That is correct. And the change doesn't have to be at *run-time*.

Comment: So a heading of class versions might be more accurate?

Comment: The class is not the entity that is saved though when serializing, and so perhaps that is why they call it Object Versions -- just a guess though.

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting But this is in the context of serialization. Say you created an object of class `Foo`, serialized it to disk. Then you modify the `Foo` class, and try to de-serialize the object on disk into an object of the *new* `Foo` class. The IDs will be different to ensure compatibility. So in this case, there would exist different versions of objects of the same class (name).

Comment: ...the class has changed ... as you stated, it is now a new class.  It might have the same name, but because it has changed I would call it a new class, hence the comments stand, an ID is per class.

Comment: after further thought, this line `The serialization process assigns a version ID to every class.` should read `The serialization process assigns a version ID to every object.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This confusion stems from the [Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) itself, where the relevant chapter was called 'Object Versioning' for years, although they have now belatedly changed it to 'Versioning of Serialized Objects'; and it's riddled throughout this and the Javadoc. It's a common confusion, or sloppiness, and you're quite right to pick it up. Tell your professor!